# Stuck in creating view

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have a table two table

SELECT MATERIAL,pkg_code FROM VW_COM_MATERIAL ;

```
MATERIAL                                                       PKG_CODE
------------------------------------------------------------ ----------
BITUMNEN (VG 30/40)                                                     
LABOUR                                                                  
PLANT & MACHINERY                                                       
STEEL                                                                   
MATERIAL (ALL COMMODITY)                                                
CEMENT
```

select pkg_code from pkg_mst

```
  PKG_CODE
----------
         1 
         2 
         4 
         5
```

Trying to make table visible as

```
MATERIAL                                                       PKG_CODE
------------------------------------------------------------ ----------
BITUMNEN (VG 30/40)                                          1           
LABOUR                                                       1           
PLANT & MACHINERY                                            1           
STEEL                                                        1           
MATERIAL (ALL COMMODITY)                                     1          
CEMENT                                                       1          
BITUMNEN (VG 30/40)                                          2   
LABOUR                                                       2   
PLANT & MACHINERY                                            2   
STEEL                                                        2   
MATERIAL (ALL COMMODITY)                                     2   
CEMENT                                                       2   
....
```

But don't know how to do so

Comment: could you provide ddl for your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a Cartesian product:

```
SELECT w.MATERIAL,p.pkg_code 
FROM VW_COM_MATERIAL w, pkg_mst p ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this : 
select * from VW_COM_MATERIAL CROSS JOIN pkg_mst;

reference : http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php